# Is there a better way of making numpy.argmin() ignore NaN values

Tags: arrays, numpy, python, nan

I want to get the index of the min value of a numpy array that contains NaNs and I want them ignored

```
>>> a = array([ nan,   2.5,   3.,  nan,   4.,   5.])  
>>> a  
array([ NaN,  2.5,  3. ,  NaN,  4. ,  5. ])
```

if I run argmin, it returns the index of the first NaN

```
>>> a.argmin()  
0
```

I substitute NaNs with Infs and then run argmin

```
>>> a[isnan(a)] = Inf  
>>> a  
array([ Inf,  2.5,  3. ,  Inf,  4. ,  5. ])  
>>> a.argmin()  
1
```

**My dilemma is the following:** I'd rather not change NaNs to Infs and then back after I'm done with argmin (since NaNs have a meaning later on in the code). Is there a better way to do this?

There is also a question of what should the result be if all of the original values of **a** are NaN? In my implementation the answer is 0

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Sure! Use `nanargmin`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([ np.nan,   2.5,   3.,  np.nan,   4.,   5.])
print(np.nanargmin(a))
# 1
```

There is also `nansum`, `nanmax`, `nanargmax`, and `nanmin`,

In `scipy.stats`, there is `nanmean` and `nanmedian`.

[For more ways](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html#manipulating-a-maskedarray) to ignore `nan`s, check out [masked arrays](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/wiki/MaskedArrayAlternative).

Comment: You have no idea how happy this makes me.